# Is there any simple way to delay favorite tweet with "twitter" gem?

Tags: ruby, twitter, delay

I would like to delay the *favorite tweet* action of a bot using Twitter gem:

```
if tweet.is_a?(Twitter::Tweet)
    puts tweet.text
    rClient.fav tweet
end
```

Probably this would be a really simple hack.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For DRY purposes I'm moving some logic to a separate method:

```
def fav_tweet(tweet)
  puts tweet.text
  rClient.fav tweet
end
```

One option is to make a separate thread and then call `sleep` in there. This won't halt execution in your main thread, so your bot can continue monitoring input.

So I'll define another method:

```
def in_delayed_thread(num_seconds)
  Thread.new { sleep num_seconds; yield }
end
```

Then change your existing code to this:

```
TweetDelayInSeconds = 30 # seems like this could be a constant

if tweet.is_a?(Twitter::Tweet)
  in_delayed_thread(TweetDelayInSeconds) { fav_tweet(tweet) }
end
```

There are other approaches to scheduling a task. But I think this is probably the closest to the 'simple hack' you ask for. For example you can schedule a one-off task with Bash - see https://askubuntu.com/questions/339298/conveniently-schedule-a-command-to-run-later but this would likely involve some refactoring of your code to enabling being called this way.

Comment: Great! This is super usefull! **Thanks!**